# error installing TSA package for R on RStudio

Tags: linux, r, installation, rstudio

so I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, and I cannot seem to find this issue anywhere else on the internet.

I am running:
Linux Mint 12(based on Ubuntu 11.10)
The latest version of R(2.15.1)
RStudio(0.96.331)

Both R and RStudio are the latest versions, so my issues with installing TSA are not based on an outdated version of R.

Here is the error message I am getting when I try to install TSA through RStudio(I installed PerformanceAnalytics and xts without any issues):

> installing *source* package ‘TSA’ ...
>
> ** Creating default NAMESPACE file
>
> ** R
>
> ** data
>
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>
> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Matrix', details:
>
> call: assignInNamespace("..Old..as.matrix", base::as.matrix, ns = "base")
>
> error: locked binding of ‘..Old..as.matrix’ cannot be changed
>
> Error : package ‘mgcv’ could not be loaded
>
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘TSA’
>
> - removing ‘/home/client/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/TSA’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>
> installation of package ‘TSA’ had non-zero exit status

I have checked my version of mgcv and it is the latest(I checked on my Software Manager and it is installed as well as the latest version).

I really have no idea of what to do now. I contemplated installing TSA manually onto my system itself, but I couldn't find a reliable website that explains how to install packages directly to R itself.

All assistance with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Per the (clear) error message `Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Matrix', details:`, you need a new Matrix package.

You could try http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu if your Mint system mixes with Ubuntu.  Else compile Matrix from source.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, you were right, it was outdated. Turns out that my distro had the old version so I couldn't do a sudo apt-get install to get the latest version. I pulled a little stunt to get it installed, so if you'd like me to share it, just let me know.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer was useful you can 'accept' it by clicking on the ticksymbol.